# Run python script in virtualenv from bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a script, which starts pgadmin4. The program starts if I run the script `python3 web/pgAdmin4.py` from its own folder, but that isn't as fast as running a command from `$PATH`...

I managed to write a shell script based on other answers from different posts, but sadly the virtual environment still doesn't work (I assume).

The shell script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

source ~/pgadmin4/venv/bin/activate
python3 ~/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py
```

The output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed these [installation steps](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-python/) no need to activate the virtual environment. You can call the executable file `pgadmin4` under `bin` directory that will be executed with the pgadmin4 virtual environment:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

~/pgadmin4/venv/bin/pgadmin4
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you provided indicates that you lack the "flask" module. Please install it through "pip install flask" or "python3 - m pip install flask".

```bash
python3 -m pip install flask
```